# Why is JodaTime timezone shifting a date time?

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

When the string "2017-04-21T17:46:00Z" is passed into the first method the resulting formatted date string is "06:46 21 Apr 2017". Why is the hour moving by eleven hours? The input strings are being provided by an HTTP server application in JSON. I thought the Z suffix referred to Zulu, ie GMT.

```
private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm dd MMM yyyy";

public static String formatTimestamp(String dateTimestamp) {
    DateTime dateTime = getDateTimeFromTimestamp(dateTimestamp);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    return fmt.print(dateTime);
}

private static DateTime getDateTimeFromTimestamp(String dateTimestamp) {
    return new DateTime(dateTimestamp);
}
```

I suspect it relates to timezones but it's not clear how or where. The code is running on an Android device in the UK, in the GMT timezone.

Comment: won't this work `return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT").format(dateTimestamp);`

Comment: What's the output of `System.out.println(DateTimeZone.getDefault());`?

Comment: @Hugo "Europe/London"

Comment: I'll add that I am using Dan Lew's Android version of JodaTime, and JodaTimeAndroid.init() is being called in onCreate() on the Application object specifically to allow JodaTime to be able to access timezone configuration. https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a test with java 7 and joda-time 2.7 (but not the Android's version)

That's how I could reproduce the problem:

```
// changing my default timezone (because I'm not in UK)
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
// calling your method
System.out.println(formatTimestamp("2017-04-21T17:46:00Z"));
```

The output is

> 06:46 21 Abr 2017

To check what's wrong, I've changed the date format to:

```
DATE_TIME_FORMAT2 = "hh:mm a dd MMM yyyy Z z zzzz";
```

Where `a` means "AM or PM", `Z` is the timezone offset/id, `z` is the timezone "short" name and `zzzz` is the timezone "long" name. Using this format, the output is:

> 06:46 PM 21 Abr 2017 +0100 BST British Summer Time

So the datetime created is 6PM, just one hour ahead of input, not eleven hours as you thought (actually if you change the format to `HH` instead of `hh`, the hours will be `18` instead of `06`).

Also note the timezone fields: `+0100 BST British Summer Time`. The first part (`+0100`) means that this `DateTime` is one hour ahead of GMT, and `BST British Summer Time` means it's in [British's Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london).

---

So, to have your output equals to your input, you have 2 alternatives:

**1.** Change your default timezone to UTC:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(formatTimestamp("2017-04-21T17:46:00Z"));
```

The output will be:

> 05:46 21 Apr 2017

If you want to change the hours to be `17:46`, change your date format, replacing `hh` by `HH`

**2.** Use the `DateTime` constructor that receives a `DateTimeZone`:

```
private static DateTime getDateTimeFromTimestamp(String dateTimestamp) {
    // creates a DateTime in UTC
    return new DateTime(dateTimestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC);
}
```

The output will be the same as alternative 1, but in this case you don't need to change the default timezone.

For me, alternative 2 makes more sense, because:

- you don't need to change the default timezone (which can cause some mess in other parts of the application)
- you already know that all dates handled by this code are in UTC time ([because of the "Z" in the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC))

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and clear answer. As you say, specifying UTC and using a 24hr format avoids the issues.

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

The [Answer by Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658125/642706) seems to be correct and informative. But FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.  For Android, see the last bullet at bottom below.

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use standard formats when parsing & generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
String input = "2017-04-21T17:46:00Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-04-21T17:46:00Z

For more flexible formatting such as you desire, convert to an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object were you can specify any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) in hours and minutes. We want UTC itself (an offset of zero) so we can use the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-04-21T17:46Z

Define a formatting pattern to match your desired format. Note that you must specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm dd MMM yyyy" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> output: 05:46 21 Apr 2017

If you want to see this same moment through the lens of a region’s wall-clock time such as `Europe/London` or `Pacific/Auckland`, apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `BST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Note the time-of-day is an hour off because of Daylight Saving Time (DST).

> zdt.toString(): 2017-04-21T18:46+01:00[Europe/London]

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/V3xDSD).

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).